# How to change many absolute position div to center of mobile screen when orientation change?

Tags: css, html, css-position

I have many absolute position div , how can i change it align to center when orientation change to center?

lets say

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:0px;left:0px">
  <div style="position:absolute; top:0px;left:11px">asd</div>
  <div style="position:absolute; top:0px;left:15px">asd</div>
</div>
```

I tried margin: 0 auto and it conflicted with the absolute also.

the reason to have the positioning as absolute because there will be animation of the div and many div will stack on a place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get rid of the positioning and setup the widths and margins for each orientiation to make this work..

This is based on the

```
 /* Portrait */
@media screen and (max-width: 320px)
```

and

```
/* Landscape */
@media screen and (min-width: 321px)
{
```

CSS methods.

I have set up an [example for you here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/KkwUk/).

To see it live either copy the url from this [jsbin page](http://jsbin.com/uqiza3/11/#preview) and view it in the [iPhone emulator](http://www.testiphone.com/) or view it in a real mobile browser.

Comment: the reason to have the positioning as absolute because there will be animation of the div and many div will stack on a place ... any way to walk around this with absolute?

Comment: No, to make things center with `margin: 0 auto;` there needs to be no positioning or floating. You can imitate positioning with margins. If you can show us your live example we can help more :)

Comment: Hey Kyle, a question — why did you use that `#wrap` `div`? Can it be done without? Thanks! (Also seems you're missing a `</div>​​​​​​​` tag?)

Comment: Hi, yes I am missing a closing tag, thanks :) I used the wrap div to enclose the .content divs. You can use media queries regardless of markup, you just select the elements you want changed based on screen size :)

Answer (score 0):

I think i have solve this by

```
<div style="position:relative; margin: 0px auto;">
  <div style="position:absolute; top:0px;left:11px">asd</div>
  <div style="position:absolute; top:0px;left:15px">asd</div>
</div>
```

because by setting the parents to relative the top: 0 left : 0 of the children div will be at the top left corner of the parent div

the more detail explanation of this positioning is at http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Answer (score 0):

So simple

```
.[you-class-name]{
 ......
 Other element for design the div
 .........................
 left: 50%; //Most Import to align center of screen, tested in all browser
}
```

Comment: Left 50% will not produce a guaranteed center, it depends on positioning, widths of parents and a number of other factors.